# Automatically fill the title of attachment/subject of email with a person's name

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I wrote code to save an attachment/create an email.

Right now, the attachment name/subject & to section of email are manually updated to reflect a person's name.

Is there a way to automatically fill the person's name based on when I filter a spreadsheet?

```vb
Sub PrintandEmail()

Dim iFolderAdrs As String
iFolderAdrs = "C:\Users\CaraBell\"
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:=iFolderAdrs & "Insert Name Commission Statement November 2023", _
OpenAfterPublish:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

MsgBox "All worksheets are successfully exported into a single pdf! """

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strBody = "<FONT SIZE = 3>Please see attached for your November 2023 commission statement. All cruise bookings (if you have any) have been reviewed by your line supervisor; any discrepancies please follow up directly with your line supervisor."

With OutMail
    .Display
    .To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a65")
    .CC = "commissionstatement@mastersofmindset.com"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Insert Name Statement November 2023" & Path
    .HTMLBody = strBody & .HTMLBody
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see any code that adds an attachment. Are you asking how to rename a file and then attach? Or how to add an attachment that you cannot rename and change the attachment name after the attachment was added?